# What electronic instruments does Oh Land use?

Tags: instruments, electronic-music

I've seen this **Oh Land** live video on YouTube and wondered:

What are these electronic instruments that Oh Land and the guy on her right play? I'd love to check them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those instruments appear to be a type of synthesizing [Autoharp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoharp).

If you read the brand name in one of the close-up shots, their instruments are [Suzuki Omnichords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnichord). The newer model (the Q-Chord) does also have a MIDI output.

Answer (score 2):

They are playing [Omnichords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnichord). Sort of an electronic take on the auto-harp. Jim James from My Morning Jacket sports one on stage as well.